# if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $c^2$ divides $ab$, prove that $c^2$ divides $a$ or $b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I have searched for help, but all explanations are not detailed enough. I know that if $c^2$ divides $ab$ then there exists an $n$ such that $ab=nc^2$. I also state that since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there is a unique factorization such that $(a_1\cdots a_i)(b_1\cdots b_j) = n(c_1\cdots c_k)^2$. This is where I get stuck.

Comment: Is it safe to say if c divides ab and gcd(a,b)=1 then c divides b.  So since ab = nc^2 and b = cm then a(cm) = nc^2 so am = nc... I think i'm going in circles now

Comment: if $a=4$ and $b=9$ then $6^2$ divides $ab$.

Comment: Infinitely many obvious counterexamples, e.g. $\  (AB)^2\mid A^2 B^2\ $ with coprime $\,A,B > 1\ \ $

Comment: what if a,b, and c were polynomials?  Would it be a true statement then.  I figured if I could show it with integers I could do it with polynomials.

Comment: Can someone change the tag?

Comment: Most likely $c$ is a prime in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is not true.

If $a$ and $b$ are squares greater than $1$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ (take for instance $a=2^2$ and $b=3^2$).

Then  take $c=\sqrt{ab}$, you have obviously $$c\mid ab$$ but $c\nmid a$ and $c\nmid b$.

Comment: Think you meant $c = \sqrt{a\,b} \ne a\,b$